# How do I enable saving of filled-in fields on a PDF form?

Tags: pdf, save, field, pdf-form

Some PDF forms [can be saved](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040ez.pdf), including all filled-in field data:

[image: can be saved]

Some others [can not be saved](http://www.umsystem.edu/ums/departments/fa/management/records/forms/human/um272.pdf), and all filled-in field data are lost:

[image: can not be saved]

**How do I enable saving of filled-in fields on my PDF form?**

Comment: I've discovered that these restrictions can be bypassed by *printing* to a file instead of saving.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use Acrobat 8, or 9, select "enable usage rights" from the Advanced menu. This adds about 20 kb to the pdf.

The other possibility is to use CutePDF Pro, add a submit button and have the XFDF data submitted to your self as an email or to a web server.  The XFDF data can then reload the original PDF with your data.

Comment: Adobe Reader XI allows form data to be saved.

Comment: In what way? I have Adobe Reader XI, and you can't save many forms. It depends on whether the form publisher enabled it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e0d.w.html

Comment: In Acrobat 8, you go to the advanced menu, and select to enable usage rights in Adobe Reader...

Comment: Where is "Advanced" menu?

Comment: I can't find the "Advanced" menu in Acrobat Reader DC 2019.010-20098

Answer (score 32):

Open your PDF in Google Chrome.
Edit the PDF as you want.
Hit ctrl + p.
Save as PDF to your desktop.

Comment: The PDF you get will save the filled info but will not have fillable forms anymore.

Comment: works well - you can then use "fill and sign" in acrobat on the resulting document but you can't delete and of the text that you put in during the first step, so I recommend that you err on the side of filling out just a bare minimum prior to doing the "save as PDF" step

Comment: @hexicle There now exists an experimental flag #pdf-form-save that allows saving PDFs with filled forms, although I haven't tested it yet

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Adobe Acrobat X to make the form, set all the fields as you want them, then click  *File, Save As, Reader Extended PDF, Enable Additional Features*. The resulting PDF form can be saved when filled in, if opened in versions of Adobe Reader before XI.

Comment: And for those with Adobe Reader XI and above you need Adobe Acrobat XI and newer?

Comment: This works. In addition, Adobe Reader DC on Mac behaves like an old Adobe Reader on Windows. (Why?)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the free foxit reader to fill in the forms, and if you pay a little you can design the forms that way you want.

You can also us iText to programmaticly create those forms.

There are free online services that allow you to upload a pdf and you can add fields also.

It depends on how you want to do the designing.

EDIT:  If you use foxit reader, you can save **any** form that is fillable.

Comment: I have used foxit, and it does not have the ability to enable saving of filled-in fields on my PDF form.

Comment: We use version 2.3 at work and it allows our customers to save the fields.

Comment: You are correct that foxit cant "enable" saving for users using Adobe, but for foxit it works.

Comment: Shame there is no Mac version of Foxit :(

Comment: Foxit Reader allows you to fill in the forms, and the form will still be fillable after you save the info on the forms. But when you open it in Adobe Reader you will still be unable to save data on the form, it will just show you what info you saved using Foxit Reader.

Comment: I use Foxit reader for .pdf form saving as follows: fill out form, export form (menu -> form -> export), then import form data when i want to continue with the exported data.  For the final version of the form, using "print" function.

Answer (score 6):

In Acrobat, click on the "Advanced" tab, then click on "Enable Features in Adobe Reader." This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In Acrobat XI, (Close Form Editing if open) File > Save As Other > Reader Extended PDF > Enable Additional Features

Comment: This is a very relevant answer for those using Acrobat XI professional.

Comment: If you use Acrobat XI Professional, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting inside the PDF file that turns on the allow saving with data bit.  However, it requires that you have a copy of Adobe Acrobat installed to change the bit.

The only other option is to print it to a PDF print driver which would save the data merged with the pdf file.

**UPDATE:**
The relevant information from adobe is at:
http://www.adobeforums.com/webx?13@@.3bbb313f/7

Comment: I have Acrobat 6.0 Professional installed.  Where is that setting?

Comment: Dead link, can you find a new one?

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Adobe Reader, Adobe Reader XI, it seems that you can save the form.

From their webpage: [Type your responses right on the PDF form, or click through and fill in the form fields. Then save and submit](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/reader/features.html)

Comment: Again, this only works if the form was created in Acrobat 8+ (or LiveCycle Designer) with the extra "usage rights" enabled. If not, no version of Reader can save form info.

Answer (score 0):

Preview in OS X seems to be able to do this out of the box. Adobe Reader shows the doc as "data typed can't be saved" but Preview was able to save my changes without hassle.

Comment: Preview has a nasty habit of letting you close without prompting to save. At least that is my experience in Yosemite.

Comment: I have just found from http://khkonsulting.com/2013/06/preview-app-killer-of-pdf-files/ that you can enable the prompting by enabling Ask to keep changes when closing documents in System Preferences > General.

Comment: This solution indeed works and you don't have to worry about adobe reader's version. This is definitely a good approach to save PDF in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

On linux use cabaret stage:

https://www.cabaret-solutions.com/download/caba-lin-64

You can fill and save cleanly