# html submit form from attached html file

Tags: html, forms, email

I've been looking around a lot for a solution, but no answer found yet.
What I would like to do: I have a number of people I want to send a form to update some personal data. So I created a html form with a submit button and would like to attache it in a email. People can open the file, complete the form and push the send button. The form needs to be send to my mail address.

Problem: upon clicking the submit button nothing happens (no reply is send).

As I don't have a website for this project, I can't use an online (published) form. So it needs to be a working file send as an attachment by mail and I should receive the data when people push the send button.

I hope someone has a solution. Thanx a lot already!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>UPDATE FORM</h1>

<form action="MAILTO:mymail@something.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"><input type="checkbox"> Ik wens niet meer deel te nemen aan klinische studies.</input> <br><br>
<table>
<tr bgcolor="#FF6601"><td width="400px" colspan="2"><font color="white" face="Arial"><b>Persoonlijke gegevens</b></font></td></tr>
<tr><td width="150px">Voornaam</td><td width="250px"><input type="textbox" name="firstname" size="38"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td width="150px">Achternaam</td><td width="250px"><input type="textbox" name="lastname" size="38"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td width="150px">Geboortedatum</td><td width="250px"><input type="textbox" name="birth" size="38"></input></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailto needs to be hooked up to an email client that will allow it and has been configured to actually do it.

I STRONGLY suggest to not rely on it but simple send them a mail with

```
[X] Ik wens niet meer deel te nemen aan klinische studies.
Persoonlijke gegevens:
Voornaam: _______________
Achternaam_______________
Geboortedatum:___________
```

An alternative that for example the Dutch Tax office uses is an editable and signable PDF

[How do I enable saving of filled-in fields on a PDF form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640063/how-do-i-enable-saving-of-filled-in-fields-on-a-pdf-form)